# JAVA - Program doesn't work right when called by another program

Tags: java

I have two programs: the first one filters images and it's called LRSR.exe; the second one, called ALGOc.exe, calls the first one and gives it the image to filter.
The programs should be able to filter 8 and 16 bits per channel images.
The procedure is that I run ALGOc, I pick an image, I tune some parameters and, when I play "execute", it sends all those information to LRSR.exe that's "do the stuff".
It almost works fine but one thing: if I pass a 16bpc image to LRSR.exe it filter the image in a crappy way.
The strange thing is that if I pick the image directly with LRSR.exe (running it from terminal instead of calling it with ALGOc) it works good and gives the right result..

EDIT - here it is part of the code (hopefully, the useful part)

ALGOc: That's the calling program

```
public int dist; 
public int numI;
public int spra; 
public int ker;
public int irc;
public String urlImg;
[...]
pb.command(folder + exe,urlImg,urlOutput, N,n,ker,ker,irc,irc);
```

His role is to pass to LRSR.exe some parameters.

"folder+exe" is the directory where the image will be saved, urlImg is the name of the file to filter, urlOutput is the name used to save the file after it's processed.

Now, let's say I have an image called IMG. I would usually run ALGOc, pick IMG, select an output folder, set some parameters and click on "execute". The ALGOc program calls LRSR.exe, gives him all the parameters it needs (the one I listed some rows above) and then LRSR.exe process the images and store a new one.
The problem is when IMG is a 16bpc image. In that case, if I follow the procedure I just explained, it gives as output a crappy image. The strange thing is that the result is almost identical to the one I get from executing it with "n" and "N" parameters tuned as 1. I thought that was the problem (wrong data pass from one program to the other one), so I made LRSR.exe write on a txt files these two parameters, and the result is that they are fine.. they are the ones I pass him.
All this mess doesn happen if I run LRSR without using ALGOc to call him. If I call LRSR directly from terminal (.\LRSR.exe IMG IMGoutputName), it works fine and the result is as it should be.

It also works fine if I use ALGOc to call LRSR but IMG is not 16bpc but 8 and that's another reason that makes me think it's not a parameter-getting problem..

Please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: It will be hard to help without seeing any code...

Comment: You are right, I'm adding some. Hope it's enough :)

Comment: when do you suppose to post your code?

Comment: Useful code would be the bit in ALGOc that kicks off LRSR, along with the exact command you use to run LRSR from the command-line.

Comment: @ChristianStrempfer there's no need. I'm editing the open post; give me a second.

Comment: @azurefrog ok, I'll start with it! I'm also adding code from LRSR.exe but it's not that easy to pick the right part..

Comment: @Blip: just done; now I'm seeing if I can upload some useful LRSR code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It came out that it was a not-working variable that I didn't knew since it wasn't my code.
Thank for you help anyway.